# Render some tags to jade template

Tags: html, node.js, coffeescript, pug, meta-tags

at my backend I have such object which I am rendering:

```
  objectToRender =
    url: getUrl
    pid: pid
    meta: ['<meta name="one" code="272387238">', '<meta name="two" code="272387238">']
    urlEncoded: encodeGetUrl

  res.render 'index.jade', {objectToRender}
```

I need to take all meta tags and pass them to index.jade:

```
each val in #{objectToRender.meta}
   meta = val
```

But everything is crashing down

What can I do here?

my error is :

> SyntaxError: /opt/rrr/yyyy/views/index.jade:7    5|
>   link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='build/css/app.css')
>   6|     script(src='build/js/plugin_manager.js')
>
> > 7|     each val in #{objectToRender.meta}    8|       meta = !{val}    9|   body    10|     strong#pid product id received:
> >
> > ## {objectToRender.pid}
>
> Unexpected token ILLEGAL  at Function (:null:null)

Comment: What is the crash message? Also you're missing parentheses in your res.render statement `res.render('index.jade', {objectToRender}) `

Comment: @BidhanA in coffeescript u dont need them

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you were using coffeescript. But anyway my question still stands, what is the crash message?

Comment: @BidhanA updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax for `each..in`. Interpolation doesn't happen inside it. Also as you have html tags inside the object, you need to unescape the value.

Try this:

```
each val in objectToRender.meta
 | !{val}
```

Comment: receiving SyntaxError: /opt/yippie/share-link/views/index.jade:7
   5|     link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='build/css/app.css')
   6|     script(src='build/js/plugin_manager.js')
 > 7|     each val in #{objectToRender.meta}
   8|       meta = !{val}
   9|   body
   10|     strong#pid product id received: #{objectToRender.pid}

Unexpected token ILLEGAL
 at Function (<anonymous>:null:null)

Comment: `#{objectToRender.meta}` - use it directly, no interpolation. See my code above.

Comment: <html lang="en">
    <head><
        <meta name="xxx" code="zzzz"></meta>,
        <meta name="121121212" code="dasdasdadas"></meta>>
    </
    <meta name="xxx" code="zzzz"></meta>,
    <meta name="121121212" code="dasdasdadas"></meta>>

Comment: Use pipe (`|`), otherwise it will use each value as a tag.... again see the above code.